# Differential of a mapping $F:X\rightarrow X$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, hilbert-spaces

I'm reading a paper and says:

> *The differential of a mapping $F:X\rightarrow X$ with respect to $v$ is:*
>
> $D_vF(x)\in{\cal L}(X)$
>
> *where $H$ is a Hilbert space and ${\cal L}(X)$ stands for the space of linear mappings acting on elements of $X$  with values in $X$.*

Which is the correctly definition of $D_vF(x)$ in this context?

Might be: $(D_vF(x),y)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{(F(x+hv),y)-(F(x),y)}{h}$ for all $y\in X$?

with $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the inner product on $X$.

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol $(D_vF(x),y)$? If $D_vF(x)$ is an element of $\mathcal{L}(X)$, then what does it mean to take its inner product with an element $y \in X$? Perhaps you mean to say that $D_vF(x) \in X$ and the mapping $v \mapsto D_vF(x)$ is in $\mathcal{L}(X)$?

Comment: precisely, I don't know what the gray quote means, that's my question. May be is $D_vF(x)(y)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{(F(x+hv),y)-(F(x),y)}{h}$ for all $y\in X$?